# .Net Regex performance issues

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some output to a RichTextBox (could a lot or a litte, its search results) and would like to apply some custom color coding.  Decided to do it with Regex and while it works, it seems to be pretty slow (~20 seconds) for 300 results.

The output is always in the same format:

```
Attribute1=Value1 Attribute2=(Value2) Attribute3="String value 3" Attribute4=
```

and so on.  So, I have 4 cases: stuff=stuff, stuff=(stuff) stuff="string of stuff" and stuff=

The following regex works just fine (matches everything it should), but is very slow:

```
(\S+)=("(?:[^"]|(?<open>")|(?<-open>"))+(?(open)(?!))")|(\S+)=(\((?:[^()]|(?<open>\()|(?<-open>\)))+(?(open)(?!))\))|(\S+)=(\S+)|(\S+)=\s
```

Do you guys see anything in particular that's slowing it down? As I'm sure you can tell, the first section matches quotes, second section matches parentheses, ect ect.

**UPDATE**
Just kidding, doesn't return exactly what I want... This:

```
Attribute1=Value1 Attribute2=(Value2) Attribute3="String value 3" Attribute4= Attribute5="Another string"
```

returns this:

```
5: Attribute1
6: Value1
3: Attribute2
4: (Value2)
1: Attribute3
2: "String value 3" Attribute4= Attribute5="Another string"
```

Looks like the quote matched all the way across to the second string, instead of considering them separately.

Comment: for the `attr=(val)` case, could `val` contain parenthesis itself?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, you could have something like attr1=value(0.0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Description

Your regex has a lot of backtracking, I just wrote a regex like this for another question. Consider the following powershell example of a universal regex.

`(?:\s|^)([^=]*)(?:=?["(]?([^)"]*?)[")]?)?(?=\s[^=\s]*=|$)`

## Example

```
    $Matches = @()
    $String = 'Attribute1=Value1 Attribute2=(Value2) Attribute3="String value 3" Attribute4= Attribute8=Value8 Attribut5=(Value5) Attribute6="String value 6" Attribute7='
    $Regex = '(?:\s|^)([^=]*)(?:=?["(]?([^)"]*?)[")]?)?(?=\s[^=\s]*=|$)'

Write-Host start with 
    write-host $String
    Write-Host
    Write-Host found
    ([regex]"(?i)$Regex").matches($String) | foreach {
        write-host "key at $($_.Groups[1].Index) = '$($_.Groups[1].Value)'`t= value at $($_.Groups[2].Index) = '$($_.Groups[2].Value)'"
        } # next match
```

## Yields

```
start with
Attribute1=Value1 Attribute2=(Value2) Attribute3="String value 3" Attribute4= Attribute8=Value8 Attribut5=(Value5) Attribute6="String value 6" Attribute7=

found
key at 0 = 'Attribute1' = value at 11 = 'Value1'
key at 18 = 'Attribute2'    = value at 30 = 'Value2'
key at 38 = 'Attribute3'    = value at 50 = 'String value 3'
key at 66 = 'Attribute4'    = value at 77 = ''
key at 78 = 'Attribute8'    = value at 89 = 'Value8'
key at 96 = 'Attribut5' = value at 107 = 'Value5'
key at 115 = 'Attribute6'   = value at 127 = 'String value 6'
key at 143 = 'Attribute7'   = value at 154 = ''
```

## Summary

[image]

- `(?:\s|^)` non-capture to ensure we're at the start of the string or substring
- `([^=]*)` capture all the non-equalsign characters upto the first equal sign
- `(?:` start non-capture block
- `=?` consume the equal sign if it exists
- `["(]?` consume the quote or open round bracket if they exist
- `([^)"]*?)` capture all non close round brackets and non quote characters until
- `[")]?` consume the quote or close round bracket if they exist
- `)?` close the non-capture block, and make this part not required
- `(?=` start a zero assertion block to ensure we don't travel into the next key/value set
- `\s[^=\s]*=` this block must have either a space followed by non space and non equalsigns characters
- `|` or
- `$` end of string to ensure we can capture the last key/value set substing in the string
- `)` close the zero assertion block

Comment: Would you mind sharing which tool you used to generate the diagram?

Comment: That's amazing... Thanks! Works great.  I also echo @Basic's question, where did that graph come from?

Comment: Looks like http://www.regexper.com/ does something similar which is a new tool in my belt

Answer (score 2):

You can try this pattern:

```
(?<attr>(?>\w+))=(?<val>(?>"(?>[^"]*)"|\((?>[^)]+)\)|(?>\S+)|(?=(?>\s\w+=|$))))
```